# Symfony 2.2 => symfony 2.3 error Deutsch locale

Tags: symfony, twig, intl

I have just done the upgrade from 2.2 to 2.3.2 version. Into the symfony 2.2, there was no error. WHen I have upgrading to 2.3.2 version I had this error.

```
Twig_Error_Runtime: An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("[ERROR 94] Validation failed: no DTD found ! (in n/a - line 2, column 21)
[ERROR 9] Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding !
Bytes: 0xFC 0x67 0x65 0x6E (in n/a - line 51, column 23)") in "MyAppBundle:Controler:index.html.twig".
```

For your information **Line 2** (above the beginning of a block) and **line 51**  (end of file) is **empty..**

Any helps?

Sam

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's a libxml2 issue. Please try to update this library.

[Proof](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/7291#issuecomment-14563561)